# Playing SHOUTcast pls file - URL in pls file lead to HTML page?

Tags: php, flash, redirect, mp3, shoutcast

I am playing some SHOUTcast radio stations in a self made flashplayer. Because the flashplayer itself does not understand pls files, I have created a pls reader in PHP that opens and reads the pls file and redirects to a file/link listed in the pls file. (I only request for mpeg/audio streams).

The flashplayer request for this file (on same domain) and will be directed to the stream listed in this pls file.

for example, when 'opening' a pls file in PHP, this give for example the following info (via `http://yp.shoutcast.com/sbin/tunein-station.pls?id=<someid>`):

```
[playlist]
numberofentries=1
File1=http://132.241.56.35:8004
Title1=(#1 - 0/10) KCSC.ASChico.com - 24Kbps MP3
Length1=-1
Version=2
```

PHP redirects the request to `http://132.241.56.35:8004` but doesn't hear anything. By opening it in the browser to test for it existence, it is a HTML-page, a SHOUTcast D.N.A.S. Status page. When opening it in winamp for example, it plays the stream. Do I miss something inhere?

Some redirects directly play in the flashplayer, so it seems that my method is OK.

What must I do to get this operational? Why is the link that suppose to be a stream a HTML page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SHOUTcast servers check your user-agent string to see if it is a browser or not.  The reason for this is that when you go to the SHOUTcast server's URL with a browser, you get the admin page.  It does this detection by checking to see if the word `Mozilla` is in the string.

Since your Flash player is going to be using the browser's user-agent string, the SHOUTcast server sends you the admin console instead of the stream.

You can override this behavior easily by appending a semicolon `;` onto the end of the requested path.

```
http://132.241.56.35:8004/;
```

This forces the SHOUTcast server to ignore your user-agent string and use `MPEG OVERRIDE` instead, which does not contain `Mozilla` and is assumed to be an audio player.

Comment: Nice succinct answers to my questions too, I appreciate it.